# How can I call multiple window.location.href in one javascript function?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I am trying to parse multiple href's with one JavaScript function. When I unremark the alert, it works fine. I'm assuming it has something to do with timing but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

I have tried the sleep command to add some sort of pause but that did not work as I expected it.

```
function pName(selectObject) {
    var x = selectObject.value;
    var y = selectObject.value.length;
    if (x === undefined) {
        x = 97;
    }
    str = '1st page here=' + "'" + x + "'";
    //alert(str);
    window.location.href = str;

    if (y == 0) {
        nxt = '2nd page - 1';
    } else {
        nxt = '2nd page - 2';
    }
    //alert(nxt);
    window.location.href = nxt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using onInput and handling the 2nd piece as it's own function.

```
onchange="pName(this);sendnew();return false;" onInput="sData(this);sendnew();return false;"

  function pName(selectObject) {
  var x = selectObject.value;
    if (x === undefined) {
  x = 97;
}
  str = 'Command 1'+ "'" + x + "'" ;
  //alert(str);
  window.location.href = str;
}
function sData (selectObject) {
  var y = selectObject.value.length;    
    if (y == 0) {
    window.location.href = 'Command 2 - B' ;
  } else {
    window.location.href = 'Command 2 - B' ;
    //alert(str);
};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to set `window.location.href` to go to `str` first, and then `nxt`. Once you navigate to page `str`, JavaScript will stop execution, and you will be **unable** to *subsequently* trigger the redirect to `nxt`; you cannot have one page navigate to two different pages one after the other.

The obvious solution would be to simply redirect from page 1 to page 3 (`nxt`) outright, completely ignoring / bypassing page 2 (`str`). However, if you explicitly want the user to visit *both* pages, you'll need to set up an automatic redirect on page 2 (`str`) **itself** to take you to `nxt`.

This can be done by simply setting `window.location.href = nxt` on page 2 (`str`), though keep in mind that you'll actually need to transfer the logic of setting what `nxt` evaluates to over to page 2 (`str`) instead of having it on the initial page 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying to code this in the page itself. This is in a .js file where I am keeping all the functions. This specific event is fired off an onChange, I need to parse multiple values on this event. When the user enters the data in the form, I need to send both pieces of information.
onchange="pName(this);sendnew();return false;"

Edit: It's also odd that when the alert is unremarked it works fine.